# ArcGIS Pro attribute rule fails when collecting from an online map in Field Maps

Tags: arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, arcade, arcgis-field-maps, attribute-rules

I am using ArcGIS Field Maps to collect building inspection records to a standalone table by tapping on a feature in a related building layer. (See [Inspect—Add a related report](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/field-maps/ios/help/inspect.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_08FD3A4D011B44DF926EC29DC7B3B60E).) The inspection table and building feature class are both stored in an enterprise geodatabase. I have created [calculation attribute rules](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/overview/calculation-attribute-rules.htm) in ArcGIS Pro to automatically copy certain attributes to an inspection record from its related building feature when the inspection is collected.

This process works when collecting inspections through an **offline** map area in Field Maps: once the edits are synced, the desired attributes automatically get copied over. However, when collecting in Field Maps through an **online** map, the attributes do not get copied over.

Here is an example of the kind of Arcade script expression I am using for my attribute rules. In this case, the rule copies the `Town` attribute from the related building to an inspection record.

```
// Don't change anything unless a `Building_ID` was added or modified
if ($originalFeature.Building_ID == $feature.Building_ID) return $feature.Town;

var relatedBuilding = FeatureSetByRelationshipName(
  $feature,
  "MyEnterpriseGDB.User.Building_Inspection_RelClass",
  ["Town"],
  false
);

// Don't change anything if a related building was not found
if (Count(relatedBuilding) == 0) {
  return $feature.Town;
}

return First(relatedBuilding).Town;
```

The attribute rule is created as follows, where `script_expression` is the above block.

```py
arcpy.management.AddAttributeRule(
    in_table=inspection_table,
    name="CopyBuildingTown",
    type="CALCULATION",
    script_expression=script_expression,
    triggering_events=["INSERT", "UPDATE"],
    field="Town",
    exclude_from_client_evaluation="EXCLUDE",
)
```

Software versions:

- ArcGIS Pro 2.9.0
- ArcGIS Enterprise 10.8.1